# Undefined method 'role?' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cancan

I have the following `abilities` model:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user, not logged in.

    if user.role? == :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
      end
      if user.role == "default"
        can :create, Homescreen
        end
        can :destroy, Homescreen do |homescreen|
          homescreen.try(:user) == user
      end
  end
end
```

And I have the following users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_create :setup_default_role_for_new_users


  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :homescreens

  ROLES =%w[admin default]
  private
  def setup_default_role_for_new_users
    if self.role.blank?
      self.role = "default"
    end
  end
end
```

When I run it on my local machine, it works fine.

However, when I deploy to heroku, I get the following error:

```
GET URL.herokuapp.com dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=158ms status=500 bytes=643
   app/models/ability.rb:7:in `initialize'
 NoMethodError (undefined method `role?' for #<User:0x00000003b56050>):

 cache: [GET /] miss

 Started GET "/" for my-ipaddress at 2012-03-19 16:14:38 +0000

 NoMethodError (undefined method `role?' for #<User:0x00000003df5d88>):
   app/models/ability.rb:7:in `initialize'

 cache: [GET /] miss
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you migrated your database?

Comment: show us `user.rb` model, i you model actually have this method or is users table have boolean field role?

Comment: @NeilMiddleton Yes, multiple times including creating a new heroku app and trying again.

Comment: is ability working on development? check User model in heroku console for role field persistance. Also try this syntax for `ability.rb` `user.role.eql?("admin")` and `user.role.eql? "default"`

Comment: @MikhailNikalyukin It works in development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restarted heroku with the following command:

`heroku restart && heroku ps:restart`

It then worked fine.

Comment: just for future - try this first, but doesn't work for everyone