# Rails 4 + CanCanCan: "undefined method `role?' for User"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan, cancancan

This is a follow-up question on *[Rails 4: CanCanCan abilities with has_many :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342953/rails-4-cancancan-abilities-with-has-many-through-association)* and I am restating the problem here since I believe context has slightly changed and after 4 updates, the code from the initial question is pretty different too.

I also checked other questions, like *[Undefined method 'role?' for User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773828/undefined-method-role-for-user)*, but it did not solve my problem.

So, here we go: I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

For a given `calendar`, a `user` has a `role`, which is defined in the `administration` join model (in a column named `role`).

For each `calendar`, a `user` can have only one of the following three `role`s: Owner, Editor or Viewer.

These roles are currently not stored in dictionary or a constant, and are only assigned to an `administration` as strings ("Ower", "Editor", "Viewer") through different methods.

Authentication on the `User` model is handled through `Devise`, and the `current_user` method is working.

In order to only allow logged-in `user`s to access in-app resources, I have already add the `before_action :authenticate_user!` method in the `calendars` and `administrations` controllers.

Now, I need to implement a role-based authorization system, so I just installed the `CanCanCan` gem.

Here is what I want to achieve:

- All (logged-in) `user`s can `create` new `calendar`s.
- If a `user` is the `owner` of a `calendar`, then he can `manage` the `calendar` and all the `administration`s that belong to this `calendar`, including his own `administration`.
- If a `user` is `editor` of a `calendar`, then he can `read` and `update` this `calendar`, and `destroy` his `administration`.
- If a `user` is `viewer` of a `calendar`, then he can `read` this `calendar`, and `destroy` his `administration`.

To implement the above, I have come up with the following `ability.rb` file:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role?(:owner)
      can :manage, Calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, Administration, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, Administration, :calendar_id => calendar.id
    elsif user.role?(:editor)
      can [:read, :update], Calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :destroy, Administration, :user_id => user.id
    elsif user.role?(:viewer)
      can [:read], Calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :destroy, Administration, :user_id => user.id
    end    
  end
end
```

Now, when log in and try to visit any calendar page (index, show, edit), I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in CalendarsController#show
undefined method `role?' for #<User:0x007fd003dff860>
def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role?(:owner)
      can :manage, Calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, Administration, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, Administration, :calendar_id => calendar.id
```

I guess the problem comes from the fact that a `user` does not have a `role` per se, but only has a `role` defined for a given `calendar`.

Which explains why I get a `NoMethodError` for `role?` on `user`.

So, the question would be: how to check a `user` `role` for a given `calendar`?

Any idea how to make things work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `role?` method in user model, like below -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations

  def role?(type)
     administrations.pluck(:role).include?(type.to_s)
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't the `role?` method a default method in `CanCanCan`? Why should I create a new one?

Comment: role? is not part of cancan

Comment: Ok, thanks for your additional comment. Let me try this out and see how things work. I will come back and approve your answer if it fixes my problem.

Comment: Ok, so eventually, i am going to switch from CanCanCan to Pundit. But your answer did fix the problem, thanks a lot.